# Jquery show hide in list not working fine

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using show and hide functions to show my menu items which are in list. They are sliding up and down on hover.

The problem is that  when the list item expands,the overall background of menu also expands but when it contracts the background also contracts and if you are trying to go an item below the expanded menu, it gets hide at once as you are out of the boundary of menu.

This behavior can be seen by hovering the second list item and after it the third list item.

Just hover on new jersey stores and than hover new york stores u will see an abnormal behavior like it collapses. i.e. it doesnt show the third list properly and results showing first

Here is a fiddle
[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h5x3f/342/)

html:

```
<div class="mega-col col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4" data-type="menu"><div class="mega-col-inner"><ul><li class="parent dropdown-submenu mega-group"><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href=""><span class="menu-title">Massachusetts Stores</span><b class="caret"></b></a><div class="dropdown-mega level2"><div class="dropdown-menu-inner"><div class="row"><div class="col-sm-12 mega-col" data-colwidth="12" data-type="menu"><div class="mega-col-inner"><ul><li class=" "><a href="index.php?route=common/location_details&amp;loc_id=24"><span class="menu-title">Burlington Mall, MA</span></a></li><li class=" "><a href="index.php?route=common/location_details&amp;loc_id=25"><span class="menu-title">Burlington Mall, MA - Cart</span></a></li></ul></div></div></div></div></div></li><li class="parent dropdown-submenu mega-group"><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href=""><span class="menu-title">New Jersey Stores</span><b class="caret"></b></a><div class="dropdown-mega level2"><div class="dropdown-menu-inner"><div class="row"><div class="col-sm-12 mega-col" data-colwidth="12" data-type="menu"><div class="mega-col-inner"><ul><li class=" "><a href="index.php?route=common/location_details&amp;loc_id=26"><span class="menu-title">Brunswick Square Mall, NJ</span></a></li><li class=" "><a href="index.php?route=common/location_details&amp;loc_id=30"><span class="menu-title">Garden State Plaza, NJ</span></a></li><li class=" "><a href="index.php?route=common/location_details&amp;loc_id=27"><span class="menu-title">Menlo Park Mall, NJ</span></a></li><li class=" "><a href="index.php?route=common/location_details&amp;loc_id=29"><span class="menu-title">Ocean County Mall, NJ</span></a></li><li class=" "><a href=""><span class="menu-title">Rockaway Townsquare, NJ</span></a></li></ul></div></div></div></div></div></li><li class="parent dropdown-submenu mega-group"><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href=""><span class="menu-title">New York Stores</span><b class="caret"></b></a><div class="dropdown-mega level2"><div class="dropdown-menu-inner"><div class="row"><div class="col-sm-12 mega-col" data-colwidth="12" data-type="menu"><div class="mega-col-inner"><ul><li class=" "><a href="index.php?route=common/location_details&amp;loc_id=31"><span class="menu-title">Galleria at White Plains, NY</span></a></li><li class=" "><a href="index.php?route=common/location_details&amp;loc_id=42"><span class="menu-title">Manhattan, NY-Toys 'R' Us </span></a></li></ul></div></div></div></div></div></li><li class="parent dropdown-submenu mega-group"><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href=""><span class="menu-title">North Carolina Stores</span><b class="caret"></b></a><div class="dropdown-mega level2"><div class="dropdown-menu-inner"><div class="row"><div class="col-sm-12 mega-col" data-colwidth="12" data-type="menu"><div class="mega-col-inner"><ul><li class=" "><a href="index.php?route=common/location_details&amp;loc_id=32"><span class="menu-title">CrabTree Valley, NC</span></a></li><li class=" "><a href="index.php?route=common/location_details&amp;loc_id=2"><span class="menu-title">Fayetteville, NC</span></a></li></ul></div></div></div></div></div></li></ul></div></div>
```

js:

```
$(".parent.dropdown-submenu.mega-group").hover(
  function() {
     $(this).children('.dropdown-mega.level2').show("500");
  },
  function(){
     $(this).children('.dropdown-mega.level2').hide("500");
  });
```

css:

```
li.parent.dropdown-submenu.mega-group .dropdown-mega.level2 {
    display: none;
}

li {
    padding:10px;
    position: relative;
    margin:auto;
}
```

Comment: format your html into something readable instead of a headache please

Comment: Please detail the problem

Comment: Is that ok for you http://jsfiddle.net/h5x3f/344/

Comment: If it's ok for your answer i will write as an answer @Ammar UI Hassan

Comment: human-formatted fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/enjeup1a/

Comment: @guvenckardas what u changed it is the same?

Comment: Just change jquery select for a tag

Comment: @GrafiCodeStudio just hover on new jersey stores and than hover new york stores u will see an abnormal behaviour like it collapses

Comment: @pinturic please see my update

Comment: @entiendoNull please see the update

Answer (score 0):

If i understand the problem, you can use :not(:animated) jquery selector.

Like this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h5x3f/345/).

```
$(".parent.dropdown-submenu.mega-group:not(:animated)")
```

Comment: i tried but nothing changed.Just hover on new jersey stores and than hover new york stores u will see an abnormal behaviour like it collapses. i.e. it doesnt show the third list properly and results showing first

Comment: what browser are you using? here works as expected, the "New York Stores" open, but the list have few items and mouse stay too bottom then open "North Carolina Stores". It sounds like design problem for me.